# javascript regex replace some words with links, but not within existing links

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Trying to replace certain words in HTML pages with the same word but as a URL linking to that resource. 
For example, replace the word 'MySQL' with `<a href="http://mysql.com">MySQL</a>`

Using the JS replace function with regex, and it's doing the replacing just fine.

**BUT it's also replacing words that are already part of URLs... which is the problem.**

For the MySQL example, it's replacing BOTH the "MySQL" text that's already linked, AND the URL leading to mysql.com, so breaking the already existing link.

Is there a way to update the inline regex (in the .replace call) to NOT do replacing in existing links, i.e.  elements?

Here's the replace code:

```
var NewHTML = OriginalHTML
.replace(/\bJavaScript\b/gi, "<a href=\"http://js.com/\">$&</a>")
.replace(/\bMySQL\b/gi, "<a href=\"http://www.mysql.com/\">$&</a>")
;
```

Here's the full sample code (tried to paste it inline but wasn't looking right with the backticks): 
http://pastie.org/private/v4l2s2c42aqduqlopurpw

Went through the JS regexp reference ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)), and tried various other permutations in the regex matching, like the following, but all that does it make it not match ANY words on the page... 
    `.replace(/\b(\<a\>*!\>)JavaScript\b/i,xxxxx`

The following regex DOES prevent the match from happening wherever the word is literally touching a slash or a dash... but that's not the solution (and it does not fix the mysql example above):

```
.replace(/\b(?!\>)(?!\-)(?!\/)MySQL\b(?!\-)(?!\/)/gi, "<a href=\"http://www.mysql.com/\">$&</a>")`
```

I've read through the related threads on stackoverflow and elsewhere, but can't seem to find this particular scenario, not in JavaScript anyway.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your regex to exclude keywords that precede the end anchor tag, `</a>`:

```
.replace(/\bMySQL\b(?![^<]*?<\/a>)/gi, "<a href=\"http://www.mysql.com/\">$&</a>")
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/PMCAE/7/) for example.

Comment: thanks! 
I updated jsfiddle to apply your regex to 2nd keyword replace as well (and updated test wording w/ better test data).  
Here's the link to the updated jsfiddle: [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/PMCAE/1/)

<br> Seeing 2 problems: *See screenshot*: 
[link](http://www.screencast.com/t/3tRF5oG1YFRi)

- the new regex is also matching (URL linking) the space preceding the keyword (i.e. "_MySQL")

- replacement is still happens if keyword is already linked, IF it's within a longer string, so breaks the last part of the link after the keyword. i.e. "link to a MySQL site"

Suggestions? Thx!!

Comment: sorry, wrong jsfiddle link. :-) Still getting the hang of jsfiddle, seems that changes are not saved until you hit update (and it creates a new url), even though you can change and run at will. make sense. correct url: http://jsfiddle.net/PMCAE/4/

Comment: Edited.  Try that one @dan.

Comment: Thanks @bozdoz , I think that's it! Only found 1 case where it breaks an already existing URL by replacing the word in the URL itself (if already linked URL contains that exact replacement term, i.e. <a href="mysql.com">whatever</a>. But "0mysql1.com" is fine). The only alternative would be to prevent it from replacing ANYTHING in an existing link, meaning between "<a" and end of link "</a>"... Any straightforward way to implement that without breaking what we've got working now? :-) Thanks!!

Comment: I have it working by changing `[^>]` to `[^<]`.  Not sure if that would break with other tests though.

Comment: Thanks so much @bozdoz , that works great!! Haven't found any cases where it's not working! :-)

Answer (score 1):

A negative lookahead should be sufficient:

```
.replace(/\bMySQL(?!\.com)\b/gi, "<a href=\"http://www.mysql.com/\">$&</a>")
```

Comment: thanks! 
The negative lookahead addition does keep replacements from happening, but is still replacing words in middle of already existing links (i.e. when "mysql" is in linked term like "link to a mysql site").
also, word "mysql" in actual url is being replaced as well, hover over first and last part of bottom right "converted" link: "link to a mysql site".
See screenshot: http://www.screencast.com/t/Ol0D1ODXs2 
See updated jsfiddle w/ better test data: http://jsfiddle.net/PMCAE/3/ 
Suggestions? Thx!!