# Javascript to search string and return number of matches

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, anchor

I have a string with a variety of html tags in it.  For example:

```
var str = "<div>My text is <a> here</a> and it is <a> very wonderful</a>.  For an example of how very great <a> my text is</a>. Please have a look</div>"
```

I would like to use javascript string.replace() to replace only the words that are not inside of a tag (anchor in this case).  It will also depend on user input, so I need to include a variable in the RegExp. I am testing first with string.match(); to verify that I only get one match.

I borrowed the code from [javascript regex replace some words with links, but not within existing links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096207/javascript-regex-replace-some-words-with-links-but-not-within-existing-links?rq=1) and just switched .replace to .match.  so I use the following code:

```
var word = "very";
var regex = new RegExp("/" + word + "(?![^<]*?<\/a>)/g");
console.log(str.match(regex).length);
```

It returns to me 
TypeError: titleText.match(...) is null
which suggests to me that no matches are found.  If I build it like this, however:

```
console.log(str.match("/very(?![^<]*?<\/a>)/g").length);
```

I get the expected number of results; in this case, 1;

Any suggestions?

Comment: *Any suggestions?* Yep, for almost all cases involving HTML where you want to discern them, don't use a regex.

Comment: Parsing HTML with RegEx? Good luck with that.

Comment: `new RegExp(word+'(?![^<]*?<\/a>)', 'g')` is `RegExp()` format, when concatenating things with a regex.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas for how to search through a string and add an <a></a> around each match of a word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't include the slashes when building up the regex as a string:

```
var regex = new RegExp(word + "(?![^<]*?<\/a>)","g");
```